# How to get a list of datatypes on Django model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm getting a list of the fields of my model like this:

```
c = Client.objects.all().first()
fields = c._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

How can I get a list of the datatypes (CharField, Int, etc) of those fields? Is there an easier way than looking up the `get_internal_type` property on each field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
raw_list = c._meta.get_fields_with_model()
```

When you do `raw_list = c._meta.get_fields_with_model()` raw_list contains something like:

```
((<django.db.models.fields.AutoField: id>, None), (<django.db.models.fields.TextField: signature>, None) etc...
```

To get a "parsed" list that only contains the name of the datatype we can do:

```
[item[0].__class__.__name__ for item in raw_list._meta.get_fields_with_model()]
```

or using **get_internal_type**:

```
[item[0].get_internal_type() for item in raw_list._meta.get_fields_with_model()]
```

In both ways you'll get a list like :

```
['AutoField', 'TextField', 'TextField', 'FloatField', 'CharField', 'BooleanField', 'IntegerField', 'ImageField', 'BooleanField'...
```

Just the code:

```
raw_list = c._meta.get_fields_with_model() 
parsed_list = [item[0].__class__.__name__ for item in raw_list._meta.get_fields_with_model()]
```